# Yeoman Backbone Require.js Handlebars Plugin i18n not working for dist build

Tags: backbone.js, internationalization, requirejs, yeoman, require-handlebars

I am using this awesome plugin for managing Handlebars templates in my Backbone app created by Yeoman: [SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin)

For some reason, the i18n translations are not picked up when running a production ready compilation created by Grunt with RequireJS.

My app config looks as follows:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        backbone: '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        underscore: '../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.underscore',
        hbs: '../bower_components/require-handlebars-plugin/hbs'
    },
    hbs: {
        i18n: true
    }
});

// Second call to assign dynamic variables and not have RequireJS break
require.config({
    locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en_us'
});
```

And my requireJS options set in Gruntfile.js are as follows:

```
requirejs: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            useStrict: true,
            wrap: true,
            findNestedDependencies: true
        }
    }
},
```

For some reason, the generated build JS file has default translations already compiled into templates. Am I missing something?

Should I switch to [RequireJS i18n plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n)?

Thanks.

EDIT:
What is the common practice to handle production build with the "require-handlebars-plugin"? Is the plugin compatible with Grunt's "grunt-requirejs" compiler?